# Which term to use for electrical appliances burning

Tags: terminology

Continuous power fluctuation causes electric appliances burning. I would like to know what is the best term to be used with electric appliances burning due to high voltage or power fluctuation.

I would like to use the above mentioned term in my following application

> It is respectfully submitted that we are having continuous power 
>   fluctuation problem in our area 37/B Jamnagar varying between 150 to
>   250 V causing different home electric appliances burning. 
>   It is therefore requested that our aforesaid problem please could be
>   fixed at your earliest possibility.

Comment: Well, the appliances are presumably "burning" because they are *overheating*.

Comment: Do not use burn for electricity unless there was actual fire. In electricity, only fuses burn - but it is very small process inside a tiny glass tube. The inflammation and actual 'burning' only takes place if electric wires heat up and isolation melts - but that does not happen in the range up to 250 v. 
My advise beyond what I wrote in the answer - just call an electrician and install surge protection. Government will not bother about your application I bet.

Comment: @javaNoobs - Surge protection will do no good.  This sounds like a classical case of "floating neutral" in a 120/240 or 120/208V service (or other voltages outside of the US).  Generally it's the responsibility of the power company to fix it, since the problem resides in their equipment.

Comment: You could say that the over-voltage is causing the release of magic smoke from the appliances.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke

Comment: @Hot Licks - not in all countries power companies care so much about responsibilities as in the USA, especially where they are funded by government. Power surge protection may include not only  surge breaker (that simply breaks off the power if outside the range) but also power inverter and accumulator(s), to output stable 220 V or whatever the standard is. Such a setting can even solve power cut offs for a few hours (lighting, computers will work, without using electric oven, of course)

Comment: @javaNoobs - You're describing a "power conditioner", which is a different (and much more expensive) beast than a "surge protector".

Comment: @Hot Licks - I know, I used to work as an electrician for a while, there is no beast, what I meant is surge protection breaker http://www.legrand.com.vn/uploads/tx_templavoila/412631_p_197312_02.jpg , an invertor and accumulator. There are also a voltage stabilizer (conditioner) - an expensive useless thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following terminology is used:

- **over-voltage** - voltage above standard
- **voltage surge** - increase in voltage above standard
- **voltage spike** - a very short high voltage jump
- **voltage sag** - voltage drop
- **under-voltage** - voltage below standard

To describe general effects on electric appliances, you can use the words

- **damage**
- **harm**
- **put out of order**
- **cause defects**

The effects of voltage surge on household appliances:

- **fuse burning**
- **short circuit** (as a result of wire heating up and isolation melting)
- **malfunction**
- **inflammation**

Examples:

[IEEE.org](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/141841)

> The switching power supplies and television receivers were damaged
> with surges between 4 and 6 kV

Article: Types of voltage problems on [ehow.com](https://www.hunker.com/13407520/the-effects-of-overvoltage-undervoltage-to-home-appliances)

Article: Electrical Spikes and Surges on [judgeelectrical.co.uk](https://web.archive.org/web/20200214095703/http://www.judgeelectrical.co.uk:80/domestic-electrical/explanations/electrical-spikes.html)

I suggest that you replace the verb 'burning' with 'damage' because 'burn' is too general and means literal burning - inflammation and fire. I suggest this wording:

> I would like to draw your attention to the fact that we have continuous voltage
> fluctuation in our area 37/B Jamnagar varying between 150 to
> 250 V causing damage to household electric appliances. Please eliminate the aforesaid problem at your earliest possibility.

Comment: There is "over-voltage" that is not a "spike" or "surge".

Comment: @Hot Licks - yes, when it is constant 240 or 250V all the time, it is over-voltage without spikes and surges, but I think I should edit my answer to add this.

Answer (score 3):

The over-voltage condition is apparently causing your appliances to *overheat*.  If the overheating is great enough, this will be accompanied by an "electrical fire" odor, though it would be rare for there to be actual sparks or flames.

Based on your description, the over-voltage condition lasts longer than a "surge" or "spike", and is likely due to what is known as a "floating neutral".  In the US this can result in voltages of up to 240V being supplied, for long periods of time, to appliances that are only designed for 120V, and the result is that four times as much power is consumed and the appliance gets much, much hotter than it should.

In the US this condition is usually due to problems with the power company's equipment, though often convincing the power company that they have a problem is a challenge.  (It helps greatly to have a licensed electrician certify that the problem exists.)

In the US the letter to the power company (if you wrote one rather than phoning or visiting in person) would go something like:

> There is a problem with the electrical service at 123 Main St.  Based
>   on our (or our electrician's) measurements, the voltage measured at a
>   standard 120V wall outlet can vary up to 150V and on occasion as much
>   as 230V.  This is strongly suggestive of a defect in your equipment. 
>   Please investigate this problem at the earliest possible opportunity,
>   as it clearly represents a significant safety hazard.

(And you should of course include phone numbers and other contact info.)